# Does Day of Judgment destroy my own creatures, too?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have read all the other questions on the card [Day Of Judgment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDay%20Of%20Judgment%5d), but none of them state if the card destroys all the creatures on my battlefield. So, in Magic, The Gathering does the card *Day Of Judgment* destroy all my creatures too?

Comment: [Plague Wind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=plague+wind) is an example that doesn't kill your own. As you see, this card is much higher in mana cost because it is a way more powerful effect

Comment: There is no concept of *your* battlefield on MTG, only *THE* battlefield. So unless the card specifies controllers, it referes to all sides of the table.

Comment: Very unclear and you could have been a little bit better when asking questions by _researching_ it first then using SE as a last resort. It seems to be a very easy question to answer. I hope you take this on board in the future. Also, the best way of thanking him is to vote and accept( as you have done partially) as it specifically says before you type the comment that  you should AVOID saying thanks or +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does. Mtg is very literal in its text, if it says all it means all, including your creatures